# Spring boot test + Kotlin = Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I am trying to do a spring boot test with Kotlin.

UserServiceTest class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
class UserServiceTest {


    @Autowired
    lateinit var userService: UserService

    @Test
    fun someTest() {

    }
}
```

error log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

.....

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBean
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBeans.java:94)
    ....
    ... 51 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bootstrapImportSelectorConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBean

   ....
   ... 24 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:591)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:953)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:898)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:881)
    ... 55 more
```

The problem is that spring can't load `ApplicationContext`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Which version of Spring Boot and Kotlin do you use?

[Here](https://github.com/larmic/neusta-code-challange-kotlin) you can find a simple demo using Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE, Kotlin 1.3.72 and JUnit 5.6.2. Maybe it will help you.